# JSON data not showing in FullCalendar

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

I am new to Laravel, coding and learning from YouTube and Stack Overflow. Thanks to all members of Stack Overflow who help me to understand the mistakes.

Now here I am Trying to show data in FullCalendar where I am getting data from controller
Below is code

**Controller**

```php
$totalbuffalomilkforcalendar = Buffalomilkrecord::select(
        DB::raw('SUM(totalmilk) as "Buffalo", (date) as start')
    )
    ->groupBy('start')
    ->orderBy('start', 'asc')
    ->get();
        
$events = [];
                    
foreach ($totalbuffalomilkforcalendar as $values) {
    $start_time_format = $values->start;
    $end_time_format = $values->start;
    $event = [];
    $event['title'] = $values->Buffalo;
    $event['start'] = $start_time_format;
    $event['end'] = $end_time_format;
    $events[] = $event;
}
```

by this I am trying to get events.

**Blade View Calendar**

```js
var date = new Date()
var d    = date.getDate(),
    m    = date.getMonth(),
    y    = date.getFullYear()

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        left: 'dayGridMonth'
    },
    eventSources:   [{
        color: 'red',   
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        events: [JSON.parse('{!! json_encode($events) !!}')],
    }]   
});

calendar.render();
```

Calendar is showing but no event is showing in the same... if i check page source data is shwoing like

```js
events: [JSON.parse('[{"title":"7.90","start":"2022-01-01","end":"2022-01-01"},{"title":"8.00","start":"2022-01-09","end":"2022-01-09"},{"title":"8.20","start":"2022-01-10","end":"2022-01-10"},{"title":"22.90","start":"2022-01-16","end":"2022-01-16"},{"title":"24.35","start":"2022-02-17","end":"2022-02-17"},{"title":"23.75","start":"2022-02-18","end":"2022-02-18"},{"title":"23.35","start":"2022-02-19","end":"2022-02-19"},{"title":"24.20","start":"2022-02-20","end":"2022-02-20"},{"title":"24.25","start":"2022-02-21","end":"2022-02-21"},{"title":"15.25","start":"2022-02-22","end":"2022-02-22"},{"title":"27.00","start":"2022-03-01","end":"2022-03-01"},{"title":"30.00","start":"2022-03-03","end":"2022-03-03"},{"title":"42.00","start":"2022-03-04","end":"2022-03-04"},{"title":"39.00","start":"2022-03-05","end":"2022-03-05"},{"title":"14.00","start":"2022-03-10","end":"2022-03-10"},{"title":"45.00","start":"2022-03-14","end":"2022-03-14"},{"title":"44.30","start":"2022-03-15","end":"2022-03-15"},{"title":"40.00","start":"2022-03-16","end":"2022-03-16"},{"title":"48.00","start":"2022-03-17","end":"2022-03-17"},{"title":"7.60","start":"2022-03-22","end":"2022-03-22"},{"title":"15.05","start":"2022-03-23","end":"2022-03-23"},{"title":"30.00","start":"2022-03-24","end":"2022-03-24"},{"title":"24.00","start":"2022-03-25","end":"2022-03-25"},{"title":"16.00","start":"2022-03-26","end":"2022-03-26"},{"title":"42.00","start":"2022-03-28","end":"2022-03-28"}]')],
```

I am definitely missing something in the code. Your help will be appreciated and thanks is advance.

Comment: What if you do `events: JSON.parse(...)` ? (without the extra `[]`

Comment: In the future, please try not to ask a new question if you've already asked it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71573777/not-able-to-show-data-in-full-calendar-from-json; you can simply edit the old question to add new details and it will be "floated to the top" of the list of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the parenthesis on the events, and it works

```
events: JSON.parse('[{"title":"7.90","start":"2022-01-01","end":"2022-01-01"},{"title":"8.00","start":"2022-01-09","end":"2022-01-09"},{"title":"8.20","start":"2022-01-10","end":"2022-01-10"},{"title":"22.90","start":"2022-01-16","end":"2022-01-16"},{"title":"24.35","start":"2022-02-17","end":"2022-02-17"},{"title":"23.75","start":"2022-02-18","end":"2022-02-18"},{"title":"23.35","start":"2022-02-19","end":"2022-02-19"},{"title":"24.20","start":"2022-02-20","end":"2022-02-20"},{"title":"24.25","start":"2022-02-21","end":"2022-02-21"},{"title":"15.25","start":"2022-02-22","end":"2022-02-22"},{"title":"27.00","start":"2022-03-01","end":"2022-03-01"},{"title":"30.00","start":"2022-03-03","end":"2022-03-03"},{"title":"42.00","start":"2022-03-04","end":"2022-03-04"},{"title":"39.00","start":"2022-03-05","end":"2022-03-05"},{"title":"14.00","start":"2022-03-10","end":"2022-03-10"},{"title":"45.00","start":"2022-03-14","end":"2022-03-14"},{"title":"44.30","start":"2022-03-15","end":"2022-03-15"},{"title":"40.00","start":"2022-03-16","end":"2022-03-16"},{"title":"48.00","start":"2022-03-17","end":"2022-03-17"},{"title":"7.60","start":"2022-03-22","end":"2022-03-22"},{"title":"15.05","start":"2022-03-23","end":"2022-03-23"},{"title":"30.00","start":"2022-03-24","end":"2022-03-24"},{"title":"24.00","start":"2022-03-25","end":"2022-03-25"},{"title":"16.00","start":"2022-03-26","end":"2022-03-26"},{"title":"42.00","start":"2022-03-28","end":"2022-03-28"}]')
```

[image]

Depending on your data and FullCalendar version, you may also want to specify `"allDay": true` for your events, as you do not appear to be sending time data in `start` and `end`

Full code working in my screenshot

```
var date = new Date()
var d    = date.getDate(),
    m    = date.getMonth(),
    y    = date.getFullYear()

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        left: 'dayGridMonth'
    },
    eventSources:   [{
        color: 'red',   
        textColor: '#ffffff',
        events: JSON.parse('[{"title":"7.90","start":"2022-01-01","end":"2022-01-01"},{"title":"8.00","start":"2022-01-09","end":"2022-01-09"},{"title":"8.20","start":"2022-01-10","end":"2022-01-10"},{"title":"22.90","start":"2022-01-16","end":"2022-01-16"},{"title":"24.35","start":"2022-02-17","end":"2022-02-17"},{"title":"23.75","start":"2022-02-18","end":"2022-02-18"},{"title":"23.35","start":"2022-02-19","end":"2022-02-19"},{"title":"24.20","start":"2022-02-20","end":"2022-02-20"},{"title":"24.25","start":"2022-02-21","end":"2022-02-21"},{"title":"15.25","start":"2022-02-22","end":"2022-02-22"},{"title":"27.00","start":"2022-03-01","end":"2022-03-01"},{"title":"30.00","start":"2022-03-03","end":"2022-03-03"},{"title":"42.00","start":"2022-03-04","end":"2022-03-04"},{"title":"39.00","start":"2022-03-05","end":"2022-03-05"},{"title":"14.00","start":"2022-03-10","end":"2022-03-10"},{"title":"45.00","start":"2022-03-14","end":"2022-03-14"},{"title":"44.30","start":"2022-03-15","end":"2022-03-15"},{"title":"40.00","start":"2022-03-16","end":"2022-03-16"},{"title":"48.00","start":"2022-03-17","end":"2022-03-17"},{"title":"7.60","start":"2022-03-22","end":"2022-03-22"},{"title":"15.05","start":"2022-03-23","end":"2022-03-23"},{"title":"30.00","start":"2022-03-24","end":"2022-03-24"},{"title":"24.00","start":"2022-03-25","end":"2022-03-25"},{"title":"16.00","start":"2022-03-26","end":"2022-03-26"},{"title":"42.00","start":"2022-03-28","end":"2022-03-28"}]'),

    }]   
});

calendar.render();
```